# How to make an restful API to add data or block into block chain

Tags: api, rest, localhost, blockchain, restful-url

I am new to block chain , my project is to just by using restful API I need to add data on to block chain.
But to do that I need to make my own private block chain I don't know how to do it.
And I also don't know which language or framework to use for making restful API to add data on block chain.
Can you help me with the tech stack and how to connect restful API to block chain.
For eg: if say http://localhost:8080/myblockchain/add I will make a post request by supplying json data to add on block chain it must add, and I should show that j have added that on the block chain.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to think that your `api` is a `block chain server` in this case you should think about how to store your blocks on other nodes or how to make a new node.
If every node is an `api` you should make a service inside them that observe other nodes to connect to them to validate their blocks by each other.